# $this->headTitle() does not work

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have in my config.ini the titles of my pages
In my Bootstrap.php I have

```
$title  = $config->title;
Zend_Registry::set('title',$title);
$view->headTitle($title);
```

In my `layout.phtml` I have:

```
echo $this->headTitle();
```

That does not work. The title is blank.
What should I do?

Comment: Are you sure $config->title is actually set?  what happens if you do: `$title=$config->title; die($title)`?

Comment: Where are you getting $view from in this example?

Answer (score 2):

Do you return the view in the bootstrap after you are done with it?

```
return $view;
```

Answer (score 2):

As @lznogood pointed out, are you setting the view correctly in the bootstrap class?

It should look something like this:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    function _initView()
    {
        $view = new Zend_View($this->getOptions());
        ...
        $view->headTitle($title);

        $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
            'ViewRenderer'
        );
        $viewRenderer->setView($view);

        return $view;
    }    // Added missing '}' brace
}
```

Another example can be found [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.application.examples.html).

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you forgetting to read it back from the Registry? You can do that with

```
Zend_Registry::get('title');
```

Comment: not really...I have that registered 

 $title  = $config->title;
 Zend_Registry::set('title',$title);

Comment: Yea but when you read it in the view, you need to read it back using Zend_Registry::get()

Comment: Im doing it:

 $title  = $config->title;
 Zend_Registry::set('title',$title);
 $varrr = Zend_Registry::get('title');

$view->headTitle($varrr);

Does not work